# Почему действия через цикл while выполняется только 1 раз/2 раз?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, api, вконтакте, while

```
$zcv = "SELECT chatid,time FROM `chats`"; 
    $nmb = mysqli_query($connect,$zcv);

        while ($by = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nmb)) {
            if ($by['time'] != '0') {
                $peer_id = 2000000000+$by['chatid'];
            $topi = array(
            'peer_id' => $peer_id, 
        'access_token' => $token_p, 
        'v' => '5.80' 
        );
    $rii = http_build_query($topi); 
    $pq = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.getConversationMembers?'. $rii));
            foreach ($pq->response->items as $user) {
                if ($user->member_id == $idsq) {
                    if ($user->is_admin == 1) {
                        $zcv = "UPDATE `chats` SET `admin`=1,`time`=0 WHERE chatid='".$by['chatid']."'"; 
                        $nmb = mysqli_query($connect,$zcv);     
                        echo "ok";      
                    }
                        if ($user->is_admin == '') {
                            $zcv = "UPDATE `chats` SET `time`=time-1 WHERE chatid='".$by['chatid']."'"; 
                        $nmb = mysqli_query($connect,$zcv);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Всего строк в базе данных 2, цикл работает только 1 раз. В чем проблема? Использую метод messages.getConversationMembers, VK API.

(Понимаю, возможно совершаю наиглупейшие ошибки, но я новичок)

Comment: Потому что переменная $nmb в цикле перезаписывается.

Comment: u-mulder, а как это исправить?

Comment: Использовать другую переменную?